# Netty Guice Integration

Tags: java, guice, netty

I know, that Netty had a Guice Integration a while ago (see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/NETTY-69), somehow this Guice Integration is missing for 3.5.3. What was the reason to remove the integration?

Has anyone ever done a manual Guice Integration with Netty and can point out some of the gotchas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found an example how to do this: https://gist.github.com/1653087

Basically the Entry point of the application extends from com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService and the Pipeline is built with Providers. All the other things are pretty straightforward "standard Guice" things.